# magento wrong product price for international orders

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, shipping

Our online shop is located in Australia. When an international order is placed the price of products in the cart are wrong, it is less than in the catalogue. Example: t-shirt 25.80, for international order's it would be $23.50. Same for the shipping cost, international shipping cost is $15, it displays $14.55
For all australian orders it shows correct product and shipping fees.
Configurable and Simple products have the same price.
Shipping costs are uploaded with an csv file.
Tax settings double checked, all include tax.

Please help!!